# remove comma in json value when import to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want import json data to mysql by php code. I have a json file and include many Object and string.

```
  "card": "2",
  "numbers": {
    "Conway": [234,872],
    "Fibonacci": [12]
  },
  "numbers2": {
    "Conway": [123,678],
    "Fibonacci": [12]
  }

}
```

and php file

```
$query = '';
$table_data = '';
$filename = "urljsonfile.json";
$data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
$array = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
{
    $query .= "UPDATE tblname SET clumnname='".$array['numbers2']['Conway']."' WHERE id=2; ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 
   $table_data .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["Conway"].'</td>
            </tr>
           '; //Data for display on Web page
}

if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) //Run Mutliple Insert Query
{
    echo '<h3>Imported JSON Data</h3><br />';
    echo ' 
      <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
              <th width="45%">Name</th>
          </tr>
     ';
    echo $table_data;  

    echo '</table>';
}
```

output now in mysql table 123,678
I want save in mysql like 123678

Comment: I don't know how you're getting `'123,678'` at all, since it should output instead `'Array'` or a notice being issued, as that is what it is. You should have two integers, `123` and `678` from that particular JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to collapse the two array values to a single string, without a comma.

`$numberString = implode('', $array['numbers2']['Conway']);`

Comment: Then please clarify your problem. @zbee's has an interesting comment that you should probably use to formulate a better question.

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to use MySQL `REPLACE` function to remove a comma from a string (VARCHAR) value.

As a demonstration:

```
 SELECT  REPLACE('123,678', ',', '') AS foo
```

returns

```
 foo
 ------
 123678
```

---

We can incorporate that function into the SQL text,

```
 UPDATE tblname SET clumnname = ? WHERE id=2
```

we just wrap that value in the REPLACE function

```
UPDATE tblname SET clumnname = REPLACE( ? ,',','') WHERE id=2
                               ^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

NOTE: any potentially unsafe values incorporated into SQL text should be properly escaped to mitigate SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

```
"... clumnname=REPLACE('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $var) . "',',','') ..."
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the downvote. This addresses the question that was asked how to "*remove comma in json value when import to mysql*", outlining a general approach to removing a comma from a string value, within a MySQL INSERT statement, using the MySQL `REPLACE` function. Obviously, this isn't the only approach. This is just one possible fix, the only change required in OP code is in the the literal SQL text. If OP was expecting "identify the problems in my code" or "fix my code", then this answer falls short of satisfying that.

Answer (score -1):

You could try it like this (@Ro Achterberg was close...):

```
$json = '{  
   "card":"2",
   "numbers":{  
      "Conway":[  
         234,
         872
      ],
      "Fibonacci":[  
         12
      ]
   },
   "numbers2":{  
      "Conway":[  
         123,
         678
      ],
      "Fibonacci":[  
         12
      ]
   }
}';

$decodedJson = json_decode($json,true);


$number = (int) implode("",$decodedJson["numbers2"]["Conway"]); 
var_dump($number); // Will output int(123678)
```

As

```
$number = implode("",$decodedJson["numbers2"]["Conway"]); 
var_dump($number); // Will output string(6) "123678"
```

EDIT: With your code and $json array:

```
$query = '';
$table_data = '';
$filename = "urljsonfile.json";
$data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
$array = json_decode($json, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
{
    $query .= "UPDATE tblname SET clumnname='".implode("",$row["numbers2"]["Conway"])."' WHERE id=2; ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 
   $table_data .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["Conway"].'</td>
            </tr>
           '; //Data for display on Web page
}

    if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) //Run Mutliple Insert Query
    {
        echo '<h3>Imported JSON Data</h3><br />';
        echo ' 
          <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tr>
                  <th width="45%">Name</th>
              </tr>
         ';
        echo $table_data;  

        echo '</table>';
    }
```

Hope that helps!
EDIT: [PHPFiddle - working example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%20$json%20=%20%27%7B%20%22card%22:%222%22,%20%22numbers%22:%7B%20%22Conway%22:[%20234,%20872%20],%20%22Fibonacci%22:[%2012%20]%20%7D,%20%22numbers2%22:%7B%20%22Conway%22:[%20123,%20678%20],%20%22Fibonacci%22:[%2012%20]%20%7D%20%7D%27;%20$decodedJson%20=%20json_decode($json,true);%20$number%20=%20(int)%20implode(%22%22,$decodedJson[%22numbers2%22][%22Conway%22]);%20var_dump($number);%20//%20Will%20output%20int(123678)%20?%3E)

OP Changed the JSON in his comment, so this should work:

```
<?php 
$json = '{ "card":"2", "numbers":{ "Conway":"119,500", "Fibonacci":"12"}, "numbers2":{ "Conway":"123,678", "Fibonacci":"12" } }';
$decodedJson = json_decode($json,true); 
$number = (int) str_replace("," , "" , $decodedJson["numbers"]["Conway"]); 
var_dump($number); // Will output int(119500) 
?>
```

Working [Fiddle](http://%20[fiddle%20link](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%20$json%20=%20'%7B%20%22card%22:%222%22,%20%22numbers%22:%7B%20%22Conway%22:%22119,500%22,%20%22Fibonacci%22:%2212%22%7D,%20%22numbers2%22:%7B%20%22Conway%22:%22123,678%22,%20%22Fibonacci%22:%2212%22%20%7D%20%7D';%20$decodedJson%20=%20json_decode($json,true);%20$number%20=%20(int)%20str_replace(%22,%22%20,%20%22%22%20,%20$decodedJson[%22numbers%22][%22Conway%22]);%20var_dump($number);%20//%20Will%20output%20int(119500)%20?%3E))

Comment: output = NULL  :(

Comment: I just added a working fiddle link. For this example, it works

Comment: but when I add this code , output NULL...I have a request(please) from you.please add this code in my php query code.so thanks

Comment: Thanks @jureW but dont worked. $query .= "UPDATE tblname SET clumnname='".implode("",$row["numbers2"]["Conway"])."' WHERE .......

Comment: please see this code.output int(0) . fiddle  [link](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%20$json%20=%20%27{%20%22card%22:%222%22,%20%22numbers%22:{%20%22Conway%22:%22119,500%22,%20%22Fibonacci%22:%2212%22},%20%22numbers2%22:{%20%22Conway%22:%22123,678%22,%20%22Fibonacci%22:%2212%22%20}%20}%27;%20$decodedJson%20=%20json_decode($json,true);%20$number%20=%20(int)%20implode(%22%22,$decodedJson[%22numbers%22][%22Conway%22]);%20var_dump($number);%20//%20Will%20output%20int(123678)%20?%3E)

Comment: You changed JSON in your example, numbers are not [123,456] anymore but {123,456}. So for this to work, you dont need implode but a simple str_replace. Check the fiddle link in my original answer